# How does Haskell avoid never-ending recursion in boolean value definitions?

Tags: haskell, boolean

Years ago I read about how Haskell compares boolean expressions and I wanted to see if I can use the same concept in my project (F#), but I don't understand how it works:

Source: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-prim-0.10.0/docs/src/GHC.Classes.html#%3D%3D

```
x /= y               = not (x == y)
x == y               = not (x /= y)
```

It makes perfect sense, but how doesn't it end in a never-ending recursion?

---

Context: in my project I have spent and unspent coins and I think they could be handled similar to booleans, where a coin is unspent when it is not spent and it is spent when it is not unspent.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> It makes perfect sense, but how doesn't it end in a never-ending recursion?

This is a typeclass, the instances should make an implementation. What you see is a default (fallback) implementation.

The compiler will normally enforce this, indeed. The class does not only provide function signatures, and default implementations, but shows:

```
class Eq a where
  -- …
  {-# MINIMAL (==) | (/=) #-}
```

the minimal means that the instances of the typeclass will either have to implement `(==)` or `(/=)` (they can of course implement both).

This is also the case for any sensical instance of `Eq`, indeed, for example with `Int`:

> ```
> instance Eq Int where
>     (==) = eqInt
>     (/=) = neInt
> ```

where `eqInt` and `neInt` in this case are implemented as:

> ```
> eqInt, neInt :: Int -> Int -> Bool
> (I# x) `eqInt` (I# y) = isTrue# (x ==# y)
> (I# x) `neInt` (I# y) = isTrue# (x /=# y)
> ```

These then have `==#` functions that work on *unboxed* `Int#` values.

Beware that a *class* in Haskell is a *typeclass*, this looks more like what one would see as an *interface* in object-oriented programming. It does not deal with (concrete) data, it just provides an interface that should be implemented.

Answer (score 12):

Those are default methods of the `Eq` typeclass. This means that if some type instantiates `Eq` and does not provide an implementation of `==`, it will be defined as `not (x /= y)`. And if it does not provide an implementation of `/=`, it will be defined as `not (x == y)`. If it doesn't provide an implementation of either method, you will indeed get infinite recursion.

Note also the `{-# MINIMAL (==) | (/=) #-}` annotation after those two lines. This means "a minimal implementation of `Eq` will define either `==` or `/=`" and instructs the compiler to produce a warning when you create an instance that doesn't define at least one of those methods.

Answer (score 9):

It would loop infinitely if you'd declare normal functions like that. But in this case these are only default definitions of the class methods. At least one of these is supposed to be overwritten by each specific instance of this class (that's what the `{-# MINIMAL (==) | (/=) #-}` says).

This situation was the subject of a CLC proposal: https://github.com/haskell/core-libraries-committee/issues/3. So in the future this situation might be addressed by simply removing the `(/=)` method from the class and making it a separate function.